# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/Matchers

Tags: java

Getting this error while running this code for RestAssured:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/Matchers
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:133)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:119)
    at newclas.main(newclas.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.Matchers
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

This is the piece of code that I'm running on my system :Not sure how to resolve the import issue. Have tried several imports but doesn't work.

```
//import io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
//import io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
public class newclas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RestAssured.baseURI="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
        System.out.println("befoire given");
        given().
        header("Content-Type", "application/json").
        when().
        get("/users").
        then().
        assertThat().statusCode(200);
        System.out.println("thank you ++ %d");


    }

}
```

Comment: We can't solve the problem we can't see, please include your code into your question

Comment: The problem isn't the stack trace or the code that you have and that compiles: it is the fact *how* you trigger your compile compared to how you trigger the actual "running" of your test. Btw: You want to read about java naming conventions. Class names should go UpperCase, always. And names should always tell the reader something, even "NewClass" wouldnt tell the reader anything.

Answer (score 1):

[org.hamcrest.Matchers](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.0.0.0/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) is not available in you class path

Add below dependency to your project

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-junit</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which assumes that the user is using Maven. What if he doesn't, or an IDE that hides it from him?!

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, I agree with you. Since there are not many details I can get it from a question, I suggested to check the dependency.

Comment: yes, thanks for your update. Actually the issue was due to hamcrest jar setup, I had added it and its got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This exception tells you that **at runtime** your class path doesn't contain the hamcrest library.

In other words: you managed to have that library showing up in the classpath for the "compile" step, but you somehow forgot about when **running** your code.

Thus the answer is to step back and ensure that the classpath setup that gets applied during compile matches the one used for running your compiled classes. So, either you do that manually, or you look into the definition of your *project* within your IDE or build tool.

Comment: I am on Android Studio, how do I manually check the Compile Time ClassPath Setup matches the runtime setup?